# My application was forwarded but I haven't received a reply. How can I follow this up with the superior who initially forwarded my email?

Tags: recruitment

About two months ago I saw a job posting for a position I really wanted. It was with a dream company and all my skills and experience closely matched the postings. However, I faced a few issues and concerns with the application, including the job application site be totally different from how jobs were usually posted and applied for.  There were technical issues with the website, and I wasn't even sure if my application had been submitted successfully.

However after submitting my application, I hadn't received any confirmation email/unsuccessful email or literally anything from the online application portal/careers site, so a month later being the individual I am I emailed the HR manager of the company directly with a copy of my CV.  I explained my passion for the company and position as well as explaining the application issues I encountered. The HR manager was really quick to reply, and forwarded my email to the recruitment resourcing manager telling him to 'please handle'.

However it's been a little over two weeks now, and I still haven't received any email from the recruitment resourcing manager. I sent the recruitment resourcing manager directly an email introducing myself about 5 days later after the HR manager forwarded my initial email onto him, but still no response.

I really don't want to give up, and I want to send another email to both the HR manager and recruitment resourcing manager. I was thinking about sending a follow up email to the recruitment resourcing manager saying something along the lines of 'I just wanted to see if you had received my previous email and if you had any questions in regards to my application' and then CC it to the HR manager. However, I'm afraid the recruitment resourcing manager may see me attempting to go over his head by CC'ing it to the HR manager?

I'd like your advice on this, in particular who should I email (should I CC it or BCC it or send an email to someone else entirely)/what should I say/any advice!

Thank you again everyone!

NB: This is different to the other 'I haven't heard back from a recruiter yet' questions, as this involves two staff, and the HR manager specifically asking the resourcing manager to follow up.

Answer (score 2):

Persistence is key when it comes to apply for jobs, if this really is a position that you want be attentive, sending follow up emails at least shows your very willing. As it stands if you don't receive a reply for a long time I wouldn't see it as going over there head, I would see it as trying to just get some form of confirmation. The worst thing that could happen at this point is you won't get the position so you've nothing to lose by trying someone else.

I will say though there's a fine line between being a nuisance and being persistent, but two weeks when they've already acknowledged you once is long enough in my eyes. Also don't be afraid to send emails to various people, sometimes in businesses people are lazy, having someone else come on board the processes may put them into gear to try and help.

You could try something like 'Hello X, I recently tried getting in contact about said position and I haven't heard anything back for a while from the person you forwarded it to. Would you mind looking into it for me in case there's been some kind of error? Best Regards you'

Comment: Thank you so much!  So you would recommend that I send this to the HR manager (rather than the recruitment manager).  Should I CC the recruitment manager in or no?

Answer (score 0):

If your emails are getting lost in a black hole then try a different communication channel.

If there's a contact number in the HR manager's email signature then give them a call. You could also call the company's reception and ask to be forwarded to them.

They've already indicated that they're interested in your application by cc'ing you when they forwarded your email. Calling them to follow up on that is the logical next step.